# fullPage.js how to display slide anchors on top in auto height option?

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I use `fullPage.js` and I think it is awesome, but on some section my height is `auto`, so when I scroll with my mouse on the section that doesn't have a fixed height, that section display on the bottom, not on the top of screen, how can I solve this?

Here is an [example](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/autoHeight.html#3rdPage). 
Footer have auto height, and if I give auto height on the previous slide section, for example, 450px, they gonna display like footer, how can I change this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please ,to help us understand the problem, edit question and add code.

Comment: here are the project smvk.rs/dadens-f/ when you scroll down with mouse on section( about or contact) you saw a empty space on top...that is not cool :) scroll down to the bottom and then scroll to the top,and that is how i want to be :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not.

That's a design decision. If you had 3 small sections one after each other they might not be able to fill the whole viewport if they scroll to the top.

And even if they did, fullPage.js would have to calculate the size of all of them and then check if they would, which can be far from ideal in terms of performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but i don't need to fill all the viewport, only that i need is when i scroll to next anchor who's have auto height,i need to stop on the top of page,to see only that section ,and the section below not section above.....is that possible?

Comment: It is not possible.